# How do I center a displaced text?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is this HTML (copy the whole thing, create a blank HTML file, and paste it):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            
            span.NoLineBreak {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            
            abbr{cursor: help;}
            img.img-hor {
                -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
                transform: scaleX(-1);
                filter: FlipH;
                -ms-filter: "FlipH";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<div align="center">
<body onload="Initialize()">
Total URLs processed: <input type="number" min="0" max="50000" value="" onchange="Calculate()" id="Input"> <button onclick="Initialize()">Reset</button><br><br>
<span id="Output"></span>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function Initialize() {
        document.getElementById("Input").value = "1"
        document.getElementById("Input").focus()
        Calculate()
    }
    function Calculate() {
        const BatchSize = 80n //How many URLs before each update.
        const MaxURLs = 50000n //The maximum number of URLs to process.
        var Output = ""
        var InputValue = BigintClamp(CorrectDecBigIntValue(document.getElementById("Input").value), 1n, MaxURLs)
        document.getElementById("Input").value = InputValue.toString(10)
        var QuotientResult = InputValue/BatchSize //BigInt automatically rounds down. By doing floor(x/m)*m you can round to specified increment, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_other_values
        var ModResult = InputValue % BatchSize
        var RemainingLeft = BatchSize - ModResult
        var LowerInterval = QuotientResult * BatchSize
        var UpperInterval = LowerInterval + BatchSize
        var PercentageWithinBatch = (Number(ModResult) * 100/Number(BatchSize))

        Output += "<table>"
        Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>URLs processed:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + InputValue.toString(10) + "</kbd></td></tr>"
        Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>Range within:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + LowerInterval.toString(10) + "-" + UpperInterval.toString(10)
        Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>Number of URLs within each " + BatchSize.toString(10) + " interval:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + ModResult.toString(10) + "/" + BatchSize.toString(10) + " (" + PercentageWithinBatch.toFixed(0) + "%)</kbd></td></tr>"
        Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>Remaining to next update:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + RemainingLeft.toString(10) + "</kbd></td></tr>"
        Output += "</table>"
        
        Output += "<table>"
        Output += "<tr>"
        Output += "<td align='right'><kbd>" + LowerInterval.toString(10) + "</kbd></td>"
        Output += "<td style='border: 1px solid white; width: 300px; height: 10px; background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 127, 0) " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) + "%, rgb(0, 127, 0) " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) + "%, rgba(0, 127, 0, 0.5) " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) + "%);'><kbd style='position: relative; left: " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) +  "%; top: 15px;'>" + InputValue.toString(10) + "</kbd></td>"
        Output += "<td align='left'><kbd>" + UpperInterval.toString(10) + "</kbd></td>"
        Output += "</tr></table></div>"
        document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = Output
    }


    function CorrectDecBigIntValue(String) {
        //This converts the user's input decimal string (negative numbers not allowed)
        //to BigInt.
        if ((/^([0-9])+$/).test(String) == false) {
            String = 0n
        }
        return CanConvertHexStringToBigInt = BigInt(String)
    }
    function BigintClamp(num, min, max) {
        //Restrict a number within a specified range, bigInt edition.
            return num <= min ? min : num >= max ? max : num;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is the text that is positioned with that gradient box (which is a progress bar), it is positioned like this, where the left edge of the text are of the number is placed on the fill edge of the progress bar:

[image]

And as you can see, the number isn't centered with the edge of the fill of the bar. I wanted to positioned like this instead:
[image]

I do not know how to extract a child's width and use it on the parent for calculating 50% of its child width. The <center>...</center> did work with -50% but that HTML tag is depreciated. I also tried finding ways to make it so that the top-center of that text zone is the “origin position” rather than the top-left, but it does not work (tried using transform-origin).

And just to warn you, the width of the text zone is not constant, any number from 1 to 50000 can be submitted and therefore its width is variable. I wanted this number, that moves with the bar, to always be centered, no matter how long the string is.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: relative` for the outer element. The element itself must be `position: absolute`. Then you can add `transform: translateX(-50%);` to center it.

```js
function Initialize() {
    document.getElementById("Input").value = "1"
    document.getElementById("Input").focus()
    Calculate()
}
function Calculate() {
    const BatchSize = 80n //How many URLs before each update.
    const MaxURLs = 50000n //The maximum number of URLs to process.
    var Output = ""
    var InputValue = BigintClamp(CorrectDecBigIntValue(document.getElementById("Input").value), 1n, MaxURLs)
    document.getElementById("Input").value = InputValue.toString(10)
    var QuotientResult = InputValue/BatchSize //BigInt automatically rounds down. By doing floor(x/m)*m you can round to specified increment, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_other_values
    var ModResult = InputValue % BatchSize
    var RemainingLeft = BatchSize - ModResult
    var LowerInterval = QuotientResult * BatchSize
    var UpperInterval = LowerInterval + BatchSize
    var PercentageWithinBatch = (Number(ModResult) * 100/Number(BatchSize))

    Output += "<table>"
    Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>URLs processed:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + InputValue.toString(10) + "</kbd></td></tr>"
    Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>Range within:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + LowerInterval.toString(10) + "-" + UpperInterval.toString(10)
    Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>Number of URLs within each " + BatchSize.toString(10) + " interval:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + ModResult.toString(10) + "/" + BatchSize.toString(10) + " (" + PercentageWithinBatch.toFixed(0) + "%)</kbd></td></tr>"
    Output += "<tr ><td style='padding: 10px'><kbd>Remaining to next update:</kbd></td><td align='right'><kbd>" + RemainingLeft.toString(10) + "</kbd></td></tr>"
    Output += "</table>"
    
    Output += "<table>"
    Output += "<tr>"
    Output += "<td align='right'><kbd>" + LowerInterval.toString(10) + "</kbd></td>"
    Output += "<td style='border: 1px solid white; width: 300px; height: 10px; background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 127, 0) " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) + "%, rgb(0, 127, 0) " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) + "%, rgba(0, 127, 0, 0.5) " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) + "%);position: relative;'><kbd style='position: absolute; left: " + PercentageWithinBatch.toString(10) +  "%; top: 15px; transform: translateX(-50%);'>" + InputValue.toString(10) + "</kbd></td>"
    Output += "<td align='left'><kbd>" + UpperInterval.toString(10) + "</kbd></td>"
    Output += "</tr></table></div>"
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = Output
}


function CorrectDecBigIntValue(String) {
    //This converts the user's input decimal string (negative numbers not allowed)
    //to BigInt.
    if ((/^([0-9])+$/).test(String) == false) {
        String = 0n
    }
    return CanConvertHexStringToBigInt = BigInt(String)
}
function BigintClamp(num, min, max) {
    //Restrict a number within a specified range, bigInt edition.
        return num <= min ? min : num >= max ? max : num;
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span.NoLineBreak {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

abbr {
  cursor: help;
}

img.img-hor {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="Initialize()">
  <div align="center">
    Total URLs processed: <input type="number" min="0" max="50000" value="" onchange="Calculate()" id="Input"> <button onclick="Initialize()">Reset</button><br><br>
    <span id="Output"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, so it has to do with `relative` and `absolute`. Does the order of stuff in the CSS <style>...</style> html tag matter?

Comment: Yes, later styling overwrite previous. But if they are completely different, it does not matter. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=F5SK5bvKa5)

Comment: I really don't know if Mozilla got that switched around on relative and absolute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

The word `absolute` sounds like it would take the position relative to the outermost html element, the highest level, while `relative` sounds like it takes the position in respect to an element 1 step out (I thought the `kbd`, the innermost element, would use the `td` element, when relative is applied on the `kbd` tag).

Comment: `relative` means relative to the normal position of the element, `absolute` refers to an outer element. Take a look at [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute). The trick is here to set `position: relative` to the outer one, so that the inner element (with absolute) refers to it. This is one way to get `transform: translate(-50%)` working. Another would be to let `kbd` relative and add `display: inline-block` to make `translate` working.